# <div> with 100% height of window, enforced by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a  element on my website that I would like to be 100% height and width of the window, even after resizing. Width is easy:

```
#myElement {
    width: 100%
}
```

But the height can cause some issues. In my head, this makes sense:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    document.getElementById("myElement").style.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

Is wrong with my logic here? Because this doesn't always work as planned. Lets assume it's not IE since (I don't think) they support window.innerHeight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with CSS, no javascript required.

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

And the mark up:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/CTGaP/

Answer (score 2):

When you specify % dimensions on an element, it's relative to the element's parent.  So, you need to make sure that all the elements above your div also have a width/height of 100%

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why 'body' and 'html' would not have 100% height by default?

Answer (score 0):

```
body { position: relative; }
div { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty direct assuming there's no other sized element between div and body:

body {position: absolute;
      height: 100%; width: 100%;}

div {position: absolute;
      height: 100%; width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

and do something else with width if you want.